# MongoDb search on date field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo collection with 'DateAdded' in ISODate format

```
{
"_id" : 4098199,
"DateAdded" : ISODate("2018-08-31T05:06:13.150Z")
}
```

so it is 1hour off then local datetime

```
LocalDatetime is 2018-08-31 06:06:13 +01:00
UTC is 2018-08-31T05:06:13.150Z
```

Using following query when i try to get records added after 2018-08-31 06:00:00 i m not getting this records as it is in UTC

```
 db.getCollection('User').find({"DateAdded":{$gte: new ISODate('2018-08-31T6:00:00Z')}})
```

How to convert UTC date while doing search on date field in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `ISODate('2018-08-31T6:00:00Z')` has a typo - it should be `06:00:00Z`. Without leading `0` ISODate helper returns `'2018-08-31T00:00:00Z'` 0am UTC and the query actually returns the document.

Secondly, there is nothing about local time. ISODate is in UTC, so 
`ISODate("2018-08-31T05:06:13.150Z")` is 5am UTC and `ISODate("2018-08-31T06:06:13.150Z")` is 6am UTC. `5 < 6`, so the `$gte` condition doesn't meet and the document is not returned.

Lastly, if you want to use local time - use `Date` instead:

```
db.getCollection('User').find({"DateAdded":{$gte: new Date('2018-08-31T6:00:00')}})
```

Will return all documents created after 5am UTC, 6am local time. Note, there is no `Z` at the end, which specifies UTC timezone.

As a recommendation - don't mess up with local time. Convert it to UTC as soon as possible and always work with UTC.

Comment: nice! new Date() working fine, i was using 'Z' in new Date()